# How to embbed ETAGS into CRUD API in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, etag

I am trying to implement ETAG in my springboot using ShallowEtagHeaderFilter:

```
@Bean
    public ShallowEtagHeaderFilter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {

        System.out.println(new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter());
        return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
    }
```

I got the ETAG shown in header when I do something like

```
curl -i -X POST localhost:8080/search/XLT
```

but I am not able to see it anymore when I request the source with the etag received in the previous one:

```
curl -i -X POST localhost:8080/search/XLT  -H 'If-None-Match:"MY PREVIOUS REQ ETAG MD5"
```

Also am not able to see 304 Not Modified and any other response.

MY GET METHOD

```
 //USER Get REQUEST
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getReport(
        @PathVariable("user_id") String userid, 
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    //Adding request type to responseList
   addResponse(true, "<HTTP-GET REQUEST>");

   //Call ProcessGetRequest which will return data fetched with that key
   ProcessGetRequest(userid);

   return displayResponseStatus();
}
```

Is there something missed that I have to do ?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` is only applied on GET and HEAD requests and it's a rather crude way of supported ETags.

Depending on how you're coding your CRUD service, Spring [supports higher-level features for such cases](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-caching-etag-lastmodified) with `ResponseEntity` or `WebRequest`.